# Computation of Distance Matrices for Binary Data in python

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean-distance, distance-matrix

I am performing a hierarchical clustering analysis in python. My variables are binary so I was wondering how to calculate the binary euclidean distance. According to the literature, it is possible to use this distance metric with this clustering technique.

[Choi, S. S., Cha, S. H., & Tappert, C. C. (2010). A survey of binary similarity and distance measures. Journal of Systemics, Cybernetics and Informatics, 8(1), 43-48.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.352.6123&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I was using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(X, metric='euclidean')` but this function uses the euclidean distance for non-binary data.

Is there any python library to calculate distance matrices based on the binary euclidean distance metric?

Comment: This may help: https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/  
converting binary to bitarray

Comment: you can calculate euclidean distance with two bitarray like this
`scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0])`

Answer (score 1):

The paper you referenced has a formula which is simply a **faster** way to computer the standard euclidean distance for binary data. In that case the `scipy` method will work fine. Is there a different distance you would like used, or is your data somehow formatted so that `pdist()` doesn't work on it natively?

Comment: I wanted to confirm whether this function is valid to use with binary data or not. Indeed, for me the formula referenced by the paper is no so clear to see that is a faster way to compute the standard formula.

Comment: The validity depends on what kind of data it is (in terms of domain knowledge, not just whether it's binary or not) and what you're doing with it. The euclidean distance induces the same topology as most other useful metrics, so in some sense the worst thing that can happen is that you get the right answer plus a distortion. That's fine in some domains and not in others. As to the speed, all the paper is doing in that section is noting that for binary vectors v and w, |v-w| is the same as (v XOR w). If your data is stored bitwise, this can be really fast.

Comment: Note that speed comment doesn't apply to, e.g., a list of floats which happen to only be 0 or 1. In Python, that carries the extra overhead of everything being an object. In most languages (Python included), that at least has the extra bits needed to represent the floats. To help you better, we really need an example of what you mean by "binary data" to be able to suggest which methods to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 - numpy**

```
from numpy import linalg, array

M1 = [[1, 1], [0, 1]]
M2 = [[0, 1], [1, 1]]

print(linalg.norm(array(M1) - array(M2)))
```

**Solution 2 - custom**

```
M1 = [[1, 1], [0, 1]]
M2 = [[0, 1], [1, 1]]

def binary_dist(m1, m2):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(m1)):
        for j in range(len(m1[i])):
            if m1[i][j] != m2[i][j]:
                sum += 1
    return sum ** .5


print(binary_dist(M1, M2))
```